# What are the relations between a kernel control path a kernel thread?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

*Understanding The Linux Kernel* says:

> A **kernel control path** denotes the sequence of instructions executed by the kernel to
>   handle a system call, an exception, or an interrupt.

and

> Besides user processes, Unix systems include a few privileged processes called **kernel
>   threads** with the following characteristics:
>
> • They run in Kernel Mode in the kernel address space.
>
> • They do not interact with users, and thus do not require terminal
>   devices.
>
> • They are usually created during system startup and remain alive
>   until the system is shut down.

1. What are the relations between the two concepts: a kernel control
   path a kernel thread?

   Is a kernel control path a kernel thread?

   Is a kernel thread a kernel control path?
2. If I am correct, a kernel thread is represented as a `task_struct`
   object.

   So is a kernel control path?
   If not, what kinds of kernel control paths can be and what kinds
   can't be?
3. If I am correct, a kernel thread can be scheduled together with processes.

   Can a kernel control path? If not, what kinds of kernel control paths can be and what kinds can't be?

Comment: `task_struct` represents not only a kernel thread, which doesn't interact with a user space. A user thread plus a kernel thread, which processes user requests(syscalls) is also represented by a `task_struct` (a single object for both user and kernel parts of the thread).

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind there is no standard terminology. Using your definitions:

> Is a kernel control path a kernel thread?

No, not under your definition.

> Is a kernel thread a kernel control path?

No.

> If I am correct, a kernel thread is represented as a task_struct object.

Probably.

> So is [it] a kernel control path?

Not under your definition.

> If not, what kinds of kernel control paths can be and what kinds can't be?

You defined it as:

> A kernel control path denotes the sequence of instructions executed by the kernel to handle a system call, an exception, or an interrupt.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do you mean that a kernel control path isn't represented as a `task_struct` object? If yes, is a kernel control path represented by some structure? (2) are kernel control paths scheduled together with kernel threads?

Comment: According to your definition, a kernel control path is just code. The data structure involved is the interrupt dispatch table the points to the code segements.

Answer (score 0):

> A **kernel control** path is the sequence of instructions executed by a kernel to handle a system call, an interrupt or an exception.

The kernel is the core of an operating system, and it controls virtually everything that occurs on a computer. An interrupt is a signal to the kernel that an event has occurred. Hardware interrupts are initiated by hardware devices, including the keyboard, the mouse, a printer or a disk drive. Interrupt signals initiated by programs are called software interrupts or exceptions.

In the most simple situation, the CPU executes a kernel control path sequentially, that is, beginning with the first instruction and ending with the last instruction.

source: http://www.linfo.org/kernel_control_path.html